# 2nd level cache invalidation with native queries

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

I have an application that uses 2nd level cache on a JBoss AS 7 installation (Infinispan 2nd level cache provider).
We have some update JPQL Queries that invalidate the cache- I wonder what will be the effect if we include some native SQL queries in our application. Will the Query cache be invalidated ? 
Also I remember using the sqlQuery.addSynchronizedQuerySpace("") instruction on Hibernate to prevent cache invalidation for some native SQL queries. Is it possible to do it also with JPA ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I came across this question when dealing with the same problem today, so I thought I'd post my findings here.

Using JPA native UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE queries does cause Hibernate to invalidate the **entire** 2nd level entity cache. As you mentioned in your question, Hibernate has a workaround for this, but it seems to not be possible to do the equivalent of Hibernate's `addSynchronizedQuerySpace()`, `addSynchronizedEntityClass()` and `addSynchronizedEntityName()` using pure JPA.

What JPA however does allow you to do is to [`unwrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)) a JPA [`Query`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) object to gain access to the JPA provider's API. If you're using Hibernate as a JPA provider, this will then allow you to use Hibernate's `addSynchronizedXxx` methods as follows:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE user SET ...");
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.SQLQuery.class)
        .addSynchronizedEntityClass(User.class);
```

It's not an ideal solution, but it will effectively allow you to prevent the entire second level cache from being invalidated.