# Usage of 2nd level cache entity with hibernate 5.2

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I recently upgraded my java application from hibernate 4.1 to hibernate 5.2 and I noticed (by looking at the SQL traces) a difference in the 2nd level entity cache usage. The cache does not get used as often as with the previous version.

To make things simple, let's say I have a very basic model: a CHILD entity with a many to one relation to its PARENT. The PARENT class is annotated with an `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`. The many to one relation in the CHILD is annotated with `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`. This should let an opportunity for the 2nd level cache to store the PARENT when fetching CHILD.

When I a load a single CHILD instance (with a query like `from CHILD where id=:id`), I see that the PARENT cache is used. If I execute the query again, the PARENT secondary select is not repeated to the database.

However, when I load multiple CHILDs at once (with a query like `from CHILD`), the PARENT cache is not used. If I execute the query again, the secondary PARENT select is repeated.

This is a big loss of performances. Has anybody encountered the same problem? Am I missing some configuration part?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After I spending more time on this problem, I discovered that it is caused by a native query executed before the read many CHILDs. This native query sets a parameter in the database session (`SET LOCAL TIME ZONE '<TIMEZONEID>'`) which is used to do some computation on dates in the user timezone.

The read CHILDs method is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` but setting the time zone parameter in the session requires a call to `query.executeUpdate()` although it does not change entities. This seems to be what is causing the cache to stop storing entities.

I am still looking for a workaround, but I know that it is not related to a specific hibernate version nor reading one vs multiple CHILDs at once.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054673/2nd-level-cache-invalidation-with-native-queries to avoid cache invalidation